# How to modify the check interval in Check_MK

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I am using Check_MK with icinga. In my Check_MK site, I found the CPU load interval is:

```
Service normal/retry check interval 60s/60s
```

It's okay usually, but when we run a performance test, we need to decrease the interval to 2-5 seconds.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that check_mk runs a single check to collect all the data from your agent/snmp, feeding that passively back into the core, you need to be aware that changing the value for that single check will implicitely change that for all referenced service checks as well.

For the general answer - I'm not sure if the check_mk config parser allows floats, but Icinga core does - maybe changing the master config templates will help here then.